# VB copy and paste in excel from one sheet to another with multiple targets

Tags: vba, excel

What I am trying to accomplish is I have an excel worksheet that is updated on a daily basis. I would like to implement a script that takes the data from those cells and add them to the next available cell on another sheet via a button. I have a basic code that works by copying a range of cells to the other sheets next available blank cell. But this is what I'm looking to do cell A1(which is a date) on sheet1 needs to copy to A7,G7,M7,A34,G34 and M34 on sheet2. Then B2,B3,B4,B5 from sheet1 copy to B7,C7,D7,E7 on sheet2. Then C2,C3,C4,C5 from sheet1 to H7,I7,J7,K7 on sheet2.

Sheet 1 cells never change only the data that the user puts into those cells change. Sheet2 cells would have to move down one after the button click

Code that I am playing with

```
Sub Rectangle1_Click()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim copySheet As Worksheet
Dim pasteSheet As Worksheet

Set copySheet = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set pasteSheet = Worksheets("Sheet2")

copySheet.Range("A1").Copy
pasteSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Application.CutCopyMode = False
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Maybe a Picture of what I'm working with will help

This is where users enter the daily data:

[image: This is where users enter the daily data]

This is where the data needs to populate to:

[image: This is where the data needs to populate to]

Comment: sounds all plausible, where do you have the problem? Can you post the basic code you have?

Comment: I can get a1 and  one section to copy but adding the others I am getting lost

Comment: You need to qualify the `Rows.Count` with the sheet. I don't know if it'll solve it, but you should do, for example, `pasteSheet.Cells(pasteSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues`  Otherwise, the `Rows.Count` is going to count the rows on whatever sheet you have active.

Comment: I think you need to re-think your structure a bit. What one day is skipped? If you just copy-past blindly without checking the data is there not a chance everything gets pasted in the wrong place? Also since you have a bunch of "ranges" on top of one another, it isn't practical for expension - i would put them horizontally (to leave room below). Finally, I think I would recommand using tables for your destinations....

Comment: ok I think i will relook at everything the final numbers get plotted on graphs  and I was trying to make it easier on some end users but I might be making it to complicated on myself